# Compiler API + Annotation Processing == double Diagnostic messages?

Tags: annotation-processing, java-compiler-api

I'm combining the Java Compiler API (JSR199) with a custom annotation processor (JSR269). Some syntax errors in Java source code supplied to the compiler are resulting in diagnostic messages appearing twice. Many syntax errors still only cause a single diagnostic message. For example, unmatch curly braces only result in a single message but an import with an invalid qualified identifier result in two diagnostic messages but only when an annotation processor is in use.

Here is some sample input that will cause the problem:

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation; // missing ".*"

public class Test { }
```

For an annotation processor I have the following. (I've tried returning false from process and I've also tried implementing Processor by hand instead of extending AbstractProcessor.)

```java
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_7)
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("*")
public class AnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is some of the code used to invoke the compiler and add the annotation processor.

```java
javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector<javax.tools.JavaFileObject> diagnostics =
        new javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector<>();

javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager fileManager =
        javac.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);

fileManager.setLocation(javax.tools.StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(tempDir.toFile()));

javax.tools.JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task =
        javac.getTask(out, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits);

List<Processor> processors = new ArrayList<>();
AnnotationProcessor ap = new AnnotationProcessor();
processors.add(ap);
task.setProcessors(processors);

Boolean compiled = task.call();

for (Diagnostic<? extends JavaFileObject> diag : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
    out.println(diag.toString());
}
```

My output looks like:

```
/Test.java:1: error: cannot find symbol
import javax.xml.bind.annotation;
                     ^
  symbol:   class annotation
  location: package javax.xml.bind
/Test.java:1: error: cannot find symbol
import javax.xml.bind.annotation;
                     ^
  symbol:   class annotation
  location: package javax.xml.bind
```

If I take out the `processors.add(ap);` line then the duplicate error message disappears. Adding multiple processors has no additional effect.

Any idea why an annotation processor causes duplicate diagnostic messages when using the compiler API? (And only for some syntax errors at that)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) the annotation processing happens in a sequence of the [rounds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/RoundEnvironment.html) and there is always at least two rounds of the processing. So the `Test.java` from  your example is compiled twice, and the processor's process method is called twice as well. Here is a self contained example:

```
public class AnnotationProcessor {
    public static final String JAVA_SOURCE = "import javax.xml.bind.annotation; // missing \".*\"\n" +
            "\n" +
            "public class Test { }";

    @SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_7)
    @SupportedAnnotationTypes("*")
    public static class MyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

        @Override
        public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
            System.out.println("Process : " + roundEnv);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JavaCompiler javac = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = javac.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
        Path source = Files.createTempDirectory("stackoverflow").resolve("Test.java");
        Files.write(source, JAVA_SOURCE.getBytes());
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjects(source.toFile());
        JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = javac.getTask(null, null, null, null, null, compilationUnits);
        task.setProcessors(Collections.singleton(new MyProcessor()));
        task.call();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Process : [errorRaised=false, rootElements=[Test], processingOver=false]
Process : [errorRaised=false, rootElements=[], processingOver=true]
C:\Users\Alexey_2\AppData\Local\Temp\stackoverflow4274340620494105881\Test.java:1: error: cannot find symbol
import javax.xml.bind.annotation; // missing ".*"
                     ^
  symbol:   class annotation
  location: package javax.xml.bind
C:\Users\Alexey_2\AppData\Local\Temp\stackoverflow4274340620494105881\Test.java:1: error: cannot find symbol
import javax.xml.bind.annotation; // missing ".*"
                     ^
  symbol:   class annotation
  location: package javax.xml.bind
1 error
```